# FILTER with a MATCH or INDEX query

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I am trying to create a workbook to log specific cases. I have a **master** sheet, which is where the start of a case is recorded. I also have a second sheet to record specific outcomes of each case.

On the second tab, I have successfully managed to copy the information needed from the "Master" sheet with the following formula `=FILTER(Master!A2:I,Master!W2:W="Yes")` This copies the information needed in a new list on the second sheet when "Yes" is selected in col W.

On the second sheet, I also need to record some new information about each case. I want to be able to copy the information on the second sheet to the "Master" sheet, but on the applicable row using the case ref. as the unique identifier.

So far I have tried this `=FILTER(Appeals!$K$2:$K,MATCH($B$2:$B,Appeals!$B$2:$B,0))`, but it is only copying the first line of data and nothing else.

The information I need to copy is in Col K, where Col B on each sheet is the case ref, which I want to eb the MATCH when copying the information from the second sheet to the Master sheet.

I am currently working on Google Sheets and I can share the sheet if needed.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Your requirement makes me think of a `VLOOKUP` kind of problem, but maybe if you can indeed share your (anonymised) sheet, it would be easier to fully apprehend your need and propose a relevant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @BenoîtWéry. Here is a copy of the sheet with anonymised data. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BpnbnoVIQRClAjnYqDV5XLft25kfP7rrgdU7ahNWOac/edit?usp=sharing

The cell I am trying to copy the formula to is on Main tab, X2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can adopt your intention:

```
=FILTER(Appeals!$K$2:$K,arrayformula(MATCH($B$2:$B,Appeals!$B$2:$B,0)), Appeals!K2:K<>"")
```

Update

==> (correspondence 1 to 1)

```
=filter(if($B$2:$B=Appeals!$B$2:$B,Appeals!$K$2:$K,""),Appeals!$K$2:$K<>"")
```

==> (active filter with two criteria)

```
=filter(Appeals!$K$2:$K,$B$2:$B=Appeals!$B$2:$B,Appeals!K2:K<>"")
```

==> <<<< -- correspondence 1 to many -- >>>>

```
=filter(ifna(vlookup($B$2:$B,{Appeals!$B$2:$B,Appeals!$K$2:$K},2,false),""),Appeals!$K$2:$K<>"")
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. It is just creating a new list and not picking up the unique ref as the MATCH. Maybe FILTER is not the right formula after all ??

Comment: may be don't use match function, please look at my update

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(B2:B1000,Appeals!B:K,10,FALSE),))
```

If not I probably misunderstood the question...